# Prob..10, Sec. 19, in Munkres' TOPOLOGY, 2nd ed: How to show that this collection is a subbasis?

Tags: general-topology

Let $A$ be a set; let $\{X_\alpha\}_{\alpha \in J}$ be an indexed family of spaces; and let $\{f_\alpha\}_{\alpha \in J}$ be an indexed family of functions $f_\alpha \colon A \to X_\alpha$.

Then there is a unique coarsest topology $\mathscr{T}$ on $A$ relative to which each of the functions $f_\alpha$ is continuous. This I can show.

Let 
$$\mathscr{S}_\beta \colon= \{ \ f_\beta^{-1}(U_\beta) \ \colon \ U_\beta \ \mbox{ is open in } \ X_\beta \ \},$$
and let $\mathscr{S} \colon= \cup \mathscr{S}_\beta$. How to show that $\mathscr{S}$ is a subbasis for $\mathscr{T}$?

My effort:

The discrete topology on $A$ is a topology relative to which each function $f_\alpha$ is continuous. Let 
$$ \{ \ \mathscr{T}_i \ \colon \ i \in I \ \},$$
where $I$ is an index set, be the collection of all the topologies on $A$ relative to each of which each function $f_\alpha$ is continuous. Then the discrete topology on $A$ belongs to this collection. So this collection is non-empty. Therefore, the coarsest such topology on $A$ is given by 
$$\mathscr{T} = \cap_{i \in I} \mathscr{T}_i.$$ 
Am I right?

Now, for each $\beta \in J$, if $U_\beta$ is open in $X_\beta$, then $f_\beta^{-1}(U_\beta)$ belongs to each of the $\mathscr{T}_i$ and hence to $\mathscr{T}$.

So $\mathscr{T}$, being a topology, contains all the finite intersections of sets in $\mathscr{S}$. And again, being a topology, $\mathscr{T}$ also contains all the arbitrary unions of all the finite intersections of sets in $\mathscr{S}$.

Thus the topology generated by $\mathscr{S}$ as a subbasis is contained in $\mathscr{T}$.

How to show the reverse inclusion?

Comment: I believe your reasoning for the coarsest topology being the intersection is fine. Moreover, you're essentially done, since the reverse inclusion is implied by the fact that $\mathcal{T}$ is defined to be the intersection of all topologies for which each $f_{\alpha}$ is continuous, but the topology generated by $\mathcal{S}$ is one such topology.

Comment: tooo much abbreviations

Answer (score 4):

What you’ve done so far is fine, and, as noted in the comments, you’ve done nearly all of the work when you’ve shown that $\mathscr{S}\subseteq\mathscr{T}_i$ for each $i\in I$ and hence that $\mathscr{T}_{\mathscr{S}}\subseteq\mathscr{T}$, where $\mathscr{T}_{\mathscr{S}}$ is the topology generated by $\mathscr{S}$. The key is simply to realize that the functions $f_\alpha$ with $\alpha\in J$ are all continuous with respect to some topology $\mathscr{T}'$ on $A$ if and only if $\mathscr{S}\subseteq\mathscr{T}'$. In particular, $\mathscr{S}\subseteq\mathscr{T}_{\mathscr{S}}$, so these functions are all continuous with respect to $\mathscr{T}_{\mathscr{S}}$, $\mathscr{T}_{\mathscr{S}}=\mathscr{T}_i$ for some $i\in I$, and $\mathscr{T}\subseteq\mathscr{T}_i=\mathscr{T}_{\mathscr{S}}$.